# Go "inheritance" - using anonymous type in a struct as a method parameter

Tags: inheritance, go

I'm trying to firm up the concept of inheritence that Go provides (rather "composition" than pure inheritence, perhaps). However, I'm failing to grasp why I can't use the "parent" type as a `func` parameter to produce a generic function that acts on the parameter.

```
package main

import "log"

type Animal struct {
    Colour string
    Name string
}

type Dog struct {
    Animal
}

func PrintColour(a *Animal) {
    log.Printf("%s\n", a.Colour)
}


func main () {
    a := new (Animal)
    a.Colour = "Void"
    d := new (Dog)
    d.Colour = "Black"

    PrintColour(a)
    PrintColour(d)
}
```

Assuming my understanding's incorrect, how can I achieve what I want in Go?

**Edit**
Note:

- I don't want to attach the behaviour to the struct
- I'd like to keep the pointer type as the method parameter because I'm working separately on a pet project and this requires I manipulate the struct passed in before then acting on it.
- In reality my `Dog` struct would have additional fields/members; hopefully this doesn't muddy the water further

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I like the answers here so far and I want to add one that allows you to do static type checking on the interface you pass in using an interface:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

type Animalizer interface {
    GetColour() string
}

type Animal struct {
    Colour string
    Name   string
}

type Dog struct {
    Animal
}

func (a *Animal) GetColour() string {
    return a.Colour
}

func PrintColour(a Animalizer) {
    fmt.Print(a.GetColour())
}

func main() {
    a := new(Animal)
    a.Colour = "Void"
    d := new(Dog)
    d.Colour = "Black"

    PrintColour(a)
    PrintColour(d)
}
```

[**On the playground**](http://play.golang.org/p/FE8sEqAs8P)

It will be possible to add further fields to `Dog`. The difference to Uriel's Answer is that calls to `PrintColour` will fail at compile time if something else than a struct implementing `Animalizer` is passed in.

Also you won't have to use a typeswitch since the compiler knows an `Animalizer` is implementing `GetColour`.

And, finally, the behaviour (printing) is separated from the struct, `GetColour` just returns the colour.

Comment: This is the approach I'd take now if I were trying this again. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

If you declare the `PrintColour` method on the `Animal` type, it will be "inherited" when you include `Animal` in `Dog`.

This is known as "Embedding" in the Go world. See [The "Embedding" section of Effective Go](http://golang.org/doc/effective_go.html#embedding) for more info.

Try something like:

```
package main

import "log"

type Animal struct {
    Colour string
    Name string
}

type Dog struct {
    Animal
}

func (a *Animal) PrintColour() {
    log.Printf("%s\n", a.Colour)
}


func main () {
    a := new (Animal)
    a.Colour = "Void"
    d := new (Dog)
    d.Colour = "Black"

    a.PrintColour()
    d.PrintColour()
}
```

Produces:

> 2009/11/10 23:00:00 Void
>   2009/11/10 23:00:00 Black

[Playground](http://play.golang.org/p/RFYcbqQdd5)

Comment: My problem with doing that (I'd explained I don't want to attach the func like that in the original question) is that it's a utility function and thus doesn't feel "correct" being attached to the type..I'll rethink my design though. Thanks.

Comment: On second thoughts, is there a way around this where I *can* pass in a parent type to the method without embedding?

Answer (score 3):

You could try it with `interface{}`

```
package main

import ("fmt"
       "reflect")

type Animal struct {
    Colour string
    Name string
}

type Dog struct {
    Animal
}

func PrintColour(a interface{}) {
    switch a.(type){
        case *Dog:
            fmt.Printf("Dog %s\n", a.(*Dog).Colour)
        case *Animal:
            fmt.Printf("Aimal %s\n", a.(*Animal).Colour)
        default:        
            fmt.Printf("hmm %s\n", reflect.TypeOf(a))

    }
}


func main () {
    a := new (Animal)
    a.Colour = "Void"
    d := new (Dog)
    d.Colour = "Black"

    PrintColour(a)
    PrintColour(d)

}
```

Comment: Good find, thanks. I guess I'll have to suck it up and redesign; I didn't want to "attach" behaviour to my structs (or create interfaces) as the behaviour is unrelated but alas I'll just keep practicing :)

Answer (score 1):

The embedded (anonymous) field can still be explicitly accessed by using its typename :

```
package main

import "log"

type Animal struct {
    Colour string
    Name   string
}

type Dog struct {
    Animal
}

func PrintColour(a *Animal) {
    log.Printf("%s\n", a.Colour)
}

func main() {
    a := new(Animal)
    a.Colour = "Void"
    PrintColour(a)

    d := new(Dog)
    d.Colour = "Black"
    // you can access the underlying "Animal" through "d.Animal"
    PrintColour(&d.Animal)
}
```

[**playground**](http://play.golang.org/p/LNuWxwUnpR)

[In the reference](http://golang.org/ref/spec#Struct_types) : the sentence after the second code block explains how you can declare an "anonymous" field, and states :

> The unqualified type name acts as the field name.

Comment: Yep, thanks, aware of this, but it's the whole type I want as I need to "inherit" common fields (e.g. `Colour`) but also those specific to one type.

Answer (score 1):

My example might not be great but you can do what you want this way:

http://play.golang.org/p/JoAlOvJthr

Essentially use an interface to define the common functionality you want to expose to the outside world for all your types and embedded types.

(My example may not be the best but it works)