# Override AvailabilityZones (Function in Interface) in AWS CDK With Go

Tags: amazon-web-services, go, aws-cdk

The [documentation](https://github.com/aws/aws-cdk-go/blob/awscdk/v2.40.0/awscdk/awscdk_Stack.go#L79) for Stack.AvailabilityZones says:

```
// To specify a different strategy for selecting availability zones override this method.
AvailabilityZones() *[]*string
```

This is my code that attempts to do this:

```
stack := awscdk.NewStack(scope, &id, &sprops)
stack.AvailabilityZones = func() *[]*string {      // this is line 22
    return &[]*string{jsii.String("us-west-1a")}
}
```

However, I get the error:

```
[andrew@localhost cdk]$ go run vpc.go common.go 
./vpc.go:22:2: cannot assign to stack.AvailabilityZones (value of type func() *[]*string)
```

How should I be doing this?

I am not sure if I have made a stupid mistake or if I need to do something completely different (what does "override" mean in go which is not OO? edit: or at least not in a way that means I can copy from [a python example](https://github.com/aws/aws-cdk/issues/9997)).

Comment: Go is an object-oriented language. just not in the same way as C++ and Java, but that's not the only way to do object-orientation. https://go.dev/doc/faq#Is_Go_an_object-oriented_language

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go has a way to inherit and "override" methods. You inherit by "embedding" another type inside a struct (where you don't name the type); see: [Go "inheritance" - using anonymous type in a struct as a method parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21527489/go-inheritance-using-anonymous-type-in-a-struct-as-a-method-parameter)

Your struct will then inherit all the methods from the embedded type.
And you can override individual ones by declaring them directly on the struct.

With a simplified example, that would look like:

```
type MyStack struct {
    awscdk.Stack
}

func (s *MyStack) AvailabilityZones() *[]string {
    return &[]string{"foo", "bar"}
}

func f() {
    // ...
    stack := awscdk.NewStack(scope, &id, &sprops)
    myStack := &MyStack{Stack: stack}
    fmt.Println(myStack.AvailabilityZones())
}
```

edit: this is what actually worked for me (andrew cooke) (but didn't solve my larger problem, so isn't deeply tested)

```
type ZoneStack struct {
    awscdk.Stack
}

func (stack *ZoneStack) AvailabilityZones() *[]*string {
    return &[]*string{jsii.String("us-west-1a")}
}

...

zstack := ZoneStack{}
awscdk.NewStack_Override(&zstack, scope, &id, &sprops)
```

(the original answer above compiles, but gives runtime errors that seem to be related to JS serialization?!)

Comment: i have something that compiles based on this, but which uses NewStack_Override as implied by https://aws.github.io/jsii/user-guides/lib-user/language-specific/go/ - once it's clear if it works i'll ether mark this as correct or post the modified version as an answer.  but this has helped hugely, thanks.